How explicit the optimiser of this optimisation problem can be?
Provided the given parameters as follows :
$\mu\in\mathbb R, \sigma\in\mathbb R_+$ are constant,  $\kappa, r, \alpha, \beta: \mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+ $ are measurable functions such that $\kappa(y)\le r(y)$ and $\beta(y)< \alpha(y)$ for all $y\ge 0$, and $\mu$ denotes a probability measure on $\mathbb R_+$.  Consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max_{\ell} &&
-\big(r(x)-\kappa(x)\big)\left(\int_{\mathbb R_+} \ell(y)\mu(d y)-\beta(x)\right)^++\int_{\mathbb R_+} \ell(y)\big(r(y)-\kappa(x)\big)\mu(dy), \\
\mbox{s.t.} && 0=\ell(0)= \inf_y \ell(y)\le \sup_y \ell(y)\le \alpha(x),
\end{eqnarray*}
where $x>0$ is chosen so that $r(x)>\kappa(x)$, and the maximum is taken overall functions $\ell:\mathbb R_+\to\mathbb R_+$. Can we obtain an explicit solution to this optimisation problem?
